# Return a data out of a promise and get it in another method

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, es6-promise

I'm missing something on how to use async/await and probably promises methods too.
Here is what I am trying to do:

**login-form-component.html**

```
<button (click)="sinInWithFacebook()">Sign In with Facebook</button>
```

**login-form-component.ts**

```
async sinInWithFacebook() {
  const loginResponse = await this.auth.signInWithFacebook();
  console.log(loginResponse); // it returns undefinied
}
```

**auth.service**

```
signInWithFacebook() {
  try {
    this.fb.login(['email'])
      .then((loginResponse: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
        const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(loginResponse.authResponse.accessToken);
      return <LoginResponse>{
        result: this.auth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
      }
    })
  }
  catch (e) {
    return {
      error: e
    }
  }
```

}

`loginResponse` will always returns `undefinied` when I want it to return the `result` object. I believe it has something to do with asynchronous methods. Can you help me out?
Thanks

Comment: because `signInWithFacebook` actually returns nothing.

Comment: Why? Shouldn't the return<LoginResponse> do the trick?

Comment: No. That return is returning to its parent Promise chain, not to the function which called `signInWithFacebook()`

Comment: To make it work, you can also add `return this.fb.login(['email']) .....`. Then your code would work.

Comment: If you're already using `await`, why `then` then? ;) `xxx = await this.fb.login(...)` etc

Comment: Thanks guys, you helped me improve my code alot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the result from `signInWithFacebook` function:

```
    try {
      return this.fb.login(['email'])
        .then((loginResponse: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
          const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(loginResponse.authResponse.accessToken);
            return <LoginResponse>{
              result: this.auth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

your function doesn't return anything. And the `try .. catch` block doesn't work that way for Promises.

```
signInWithFacebook():Promise<LoginResponse> {
  return this.fb.login(['email'])
    .then((loginResponse: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
      const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(loginResponse.authResponse.accessToken);
      //my guts tell me that `this.auth.auth.signInWithCredential` is async as well.
      //so let the promise chain deal with that/resolve that
      return this.auth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    })
    .then(
      result => ({ result }),
      error => ({ error })
    );
}
```